# Petersen graph is tripartite

Tags: graph-theory

Please help me prove Petersen graph is tripartite.

I know that is not bipartite by brute force, however I'm not sure how toextend this for Tripartite. I have a only clue that The chromatic number of the Petersen graph is 3 and it has 5 cycle.

Do we have any standard proof or do we have to assume things inorder to prove this. kindly advise.

Comment: Well, since you need to prove that it's tripartite, giving a tripartition (or a 3-coloration) is enough.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be so kind to eloborate the above.

Comment: It would be better if you can solve it by yourself. Just draw Petersen graph on a paper and try to color its vertices.

Comment: What is your definition of the Petersen graph?

Comment: Petersen graph is an undirected graph with 10 vertices and 15 edges. It is a cubic symmetric graph and is nonplanar.

Comment: @Allan That is not a **definition** of the Petersen graph. There is a nonplanar cubic symmetric graph with $10$ vertices which is bipartite and Hamiltonian so it is **not** the Petersen graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Petersen graph can be defined as the graph whose vertices are the two-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\},$ with two vertices being adjacent if they are disjoint sets.

The Petersen graph is not $2$-colorable (bipartite) because it contains a $5$-cycle, e.g., the cycle
$$\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,1\},\{2,3\},\{4,5\},\{1,2\}.$$

We can show that the Petersen graph is $3$-colorable (tripartite) by exhibiting a proper $3$-coloring of the vertices:

Color a vertex red if its least element is $1$; i.e., the red vertices are
$$\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\}.$$
Color a vertex white if its least element is $2$; i.e., the white vertices are
$$\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\}.$$
Color the remaining vertices blue; i.e., the blue vertices are
$$\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}.$$

Comment: Thank you again. Accepted.

Comment: A [Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph), nice...

Answer (score 2):

Use "This drawing with order-3 symmetry"

[image]

(colors added to figure given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#Hamiltonian_paths_and_cycles))

Answer (score 0):

Since the chromatic number is three, i.e., vertices can be colored with three colors such that there is no edge between the same color vertices. 
Now consider a tri-partition of vertex set, where each partition consists of verices of same color.

Comment: can you please show me the color code of its vertices. Will that be sufficient for this proof?